# Count number of processes running on Windows via PHP

Tags: php

Do you know if there is a way in Windows to count the number of processes running via PHP?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with a simple google search you can use this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.win32-ps-list-procs.php

```
$processList = win32_ps_list_procs();
if($processList === false) {
    // Do error handling here. We use die() for example
    die('Failed to obtain the list of processes');
}
$count = count($processList);
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do count(); You should be able to upvote mod edits. :D

Comment: Yeah, also you shouldn't use the `@` operator unless you have good reason for that. (Don't trust all that examples on php.net). Instead you should do proper error handling. Let me add that...

Comment: My google skills need work because I could not find this. Thank you sir.

Comment: This link leads to a 404 now